# "get string array" from structure array of structure{id: Int, name: string} without loop. fastest way if possible?

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, data-structures

As a demo I ask for simple structure.
Code looks like:

```
struct MainActModel{
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}
```

I want this array -> array of element.name with fastest way.
Normally I convert using loop but it takes time.

My original structure looks like:

```
struct MainContryModel{
    let id: Int
    let ContryName: String
    let ActList: [MainActModel]
    let freAskedIds: [MainActModel]
}

struct MainActModel{
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let ActChapteers: [MainListModel]
}

struct MainListModel{
    let id: Int
    let title: String
    let subList: [SubList]
}

struct SubList{
    let title: String
    let description: [String]
}
```

Ignore if not possible faster than loop.

My working code looks like:

```
let arrStrList:[String] = []
for i in arrList{
    arrList.append(i.ContryName)
}
```

but it is time consuming.

Comment: Have you tried the `map` function? You can use it with a `KeyPath` too. Try `myArray.map(\.name)`

Comment: For iterating through a simple array of structs and extracting a simple element your duration will always be pretty much the same whatever mechanism you use, at O(n), as you have to touch each item.  The compiler is likely to optimise whatever mechanism you use (for loop, map, etc) to a very similar output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the map function to transform the array of MainActModel elements into an array of their name properties

```
let mainActModels: [MainActModel] = ...
let names = mainActModels.map { $0.name }
```

This code avoids the use of a loop and should be faster. Note that the time complexity of the map function is O(n), which is the same as a loop. However, the map function is a built-in method optimized for performance, so it may be faster than a handwritten loop in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. Boost the performance

There are a lot of ways to enhance the performance of this. For example by reserving the capacity for the `arrList`, you can significantly enhance the performance:

```
stringArray.reserveCapacity(objectArray.count)
```

---

#### 2. Make it even better

Also, you can use `makeIterator` and `underestimatedCount` for better performance like the `map` function original implementation.

But if you don't know much about the performance of each of these, you may want to stick to the standard library implementation:

```
arrStrList.map(\.name)
```

---

#### 3. Consider the use case

At the end, there is no silver bullet for the performance and you must consider your usecase. For example if you are going to use the result conditional, you may need to add `.lazy` to your sequence:

```
arrStrList.lazy.map(\.name)
```